# I have issue in join while fetching data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table and structure as below :

1. abc

```
     id name    education
     1  test1   a
     2  test2   b
     3  test3   c
```

2. pqr

```
    id  name    abcid
    1   takr    1
    2   test21  1
    3   testlll 2
```

3. xyz

```
    id  name    abcid
    1   takr    2
    2   test21  2
    3   testlll 3
```

I want all the data based on abc table id

below is the query

```
SELECT d.ID,l.VALUE_ID as RI_ID,l.UF_CRM_1486370412 as RI_AMT, f.VALUE_ID as Finance_Id , f.UF_CRM_1595053941 as FI_AMT
FROM  b_uts_crm_lead as l
JOIN b_crm_deal as d
ON d.ID = l.UF_CRM_1600342528 
JOIN b_uts_crm_financeaddition as f
ON d.ID = f.UF_CRM_1600350766
```

Comment: so whats your question? And your query does not fit the table definition you posted.

Comment: "I want all the data" isn't particularly descriptive.  Your query also doesn't match your data.

Comment: I need to fetch all the data based on abc id? From first table id i need to fetch all the data related to other 2 tables

Comment: Please provide desired data example

Comment: Cureently i m getting only common data based on id in both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want `left join`:

```
select . . .    -- the columns you want
from abc left join
     xyz
     on xyz.abcid = abc.id left join
     pqr
     on pqr.abcid = abc.id;
```

Comment: In this i m not getting first table id .